# JQuery Contact Form

Tags: php, jquery

I have been working off a tutorial on Net Tuts to create a contact form for my website. Link for tutorial below:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

I have it functioning however have been dabbling with a ways to add an additional field into the form for comments. All other fields are submitted fine to both email addresses (my website email and the sender gets copy also) but the comment field keeps displaying "No comment entered"

The code for my form is as follows:

[contact.php page]

```
<div id="content">
<div id="contact_form">
    <div class="padding">
<h2>Contact Me</h2>
<p>If you would like to contact me regarding a quote or indeed anything relating to the website
please use the form below and I will get to you as soon as possible. Thanks!</p>
<form name="contact" method="post" action="">
   <fieldset>
     <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />
     <label class="error" for="name" id="name_error">This field is required.</label><br />

     <label for="email" id="email_label">Return Email</label>
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />
     <label class="error" for="email" id="email_error">This field is required.</label><br />

     <label for="phone" id="phone_label">Return Phone</label>
     <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />
     <label class="error" for="phone" id="phone_error">This field is required.</label><br />


     <label for="comment" id="comment_label">Comment</label>
     <textarea name="comments" rows="10" cols="30" ></textarea>
     <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" size="300" value="" class="text-input" />
     <label class="error" for="comment" id="comment_error">This field is required.</label><br />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send" />
   </fieldset>
 </form>    
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[process.php]

```
   <?php
if ((isset($_POST['name'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['name'])) > 0)) {
    $name = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
} else {$name = 'No name entered';}
if ((isset($_POST['email'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['email'])) > 0)) {
    $email = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
} else {$email = 'No email entered';}
if ((isset($_POST['phone'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['phone'])) > 0)) {
    $phone = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['phone']));
} else {$phone = 'No phone entered';}
if ((isset($_POST['comment'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['comment'])) > 0)) {
    $comment = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['comment']));
} else {$comment = 'No comment entered';}
ob_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="550" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr bgcolor="#eeffee">
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><?=$name;?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeeeff">
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><?=$email;?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeffee">
    <td>Phone</td>
    <td><?=$phone;?></td>
  </tr>
   <tr bgcolor="#eeffee">
    <td>Comment</td>
    <td><?=$comment;?></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$body = ob_get_contents();

$to = '';
$email = '';
$fromaddress = "";
$fromname = "Online Contact";
$test = $comment;

require("phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->From     = $_POST['email'];
$mail->FromName = "Contact Form";
$mail->AddAddress("contact@ncwebcreative.co.uk","Name 2");


$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject  =  "Contact form submitted";
$mail->Body     =  $body;
$mail->AltBody  =  "This is the text-only body";

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    $recipient = 'your_email@example.com';
    $subject = 'Contact form failed';
    $content = $body;
  mail($recipient, $subject, $content, "From: mail@yourdomain.com\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nX-Mailer: DT_formmail");
  exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: you have comment `<input>` and comments `<textarea>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to change the code:

```
$("input#comment").focus();
```

to

```
$("textarea#comment").focus();
```

to be able to use text areas with jquery

Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of this line:

```
<input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" size="300" value="" class="text-input" />
```

You have a text input field inside of a text area. You might need to add the `id="comment"` to your text area depending on the rest of your code.

Also change the text areas name to comment.

Comment: 'code'    <label for="comment" id="comment_label">Comment</label>
      <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="10" cols="30" ></textarea>
      <label class="error" for="comment" id="comment_error">This field is required.</label><br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send" />
    </fieldset>
  </form> 'code'

Comment: Thanks for everyone getting back to me so promptly btw :) but it still doesn't work still getting 'no comment entered'

Comment: where are you typing the comment? in the textarea or in the input field?

Comment: Try just this and see what you get.  <label for="comment" id="comment_label">Comment</label>
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="10" cols="30" ></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send" />

Comment: Into the text area the input field has been removed. I have removed my code and replaced it with that line but still get 'No comment Entered'